# Pydantic field with custom data type and mypy

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, pydantic

Following the [Custom Data Types](https://docs.pydantic.dev/usage/types/#custom-data-types) example from Pydantic docs, I made my own `Timestamp` data type subclassing `str`. Everything works OK except that mypy is complaining when passing literal string values where it expects a `Timestamp` object.

Considering the code below, how can I explain to mypy that line 25 is not an error?

I tried with `Annotate[str, Timestamp]`, but only to get the reverse error (line 25 is OK, but line 29 gets `error: "<typing special form>" not callable`).

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from pydantic import BaseModel


class Timestamp(str):
    @classmethod
    def __get_validators__(cls):
        yield cls.validate

    @classmethod
    def validate(cls, value: str) -> Timestamp:
        ...
        return cls(value)


class Foo(BaseModel):
    title: str
    bar: Timestamp


def _main() -> None:
    f1 = Foo(
        title="F1",
        bar="2023-04-05T06:07:08Z",  # line 25: error: Argument "bar" to "Foo" has incompatible type "str"; expected "Timestamp"  [arg-type]
    )
    f2 = Foo(
        title="F2",
        bar=Timestamp("2023-04-05T06:07:08Z"),  # line 29
    )
```

Comment: Line 25 _is_ an error. You defined the type of `bar` to be `Timestamp`, not `str`. `Timestamp` is a subtype of `str`, which means a variable annotated with `str` will also accept a `Timestamp` object, but not the other way around. Just because Pydantic is lenient enough to coerce wrong data types, does not make this type safe.

Answer (score 2):

### Basic type safety

The error is correct. If `T` is a subtype of `S`, annotating `x: S` means you can also assign a value of type `T` to the variable `x`, but **not the other way around**.

This can be easily demonstrated with `int` and `bool` since the latter is a subtype of the former.

Try this with `mypy`: ([playground here](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=20cdc016701643db23c06aadad942a32))

```py
x: int
y: bool

x = 1      # passes
x = True   # passes
y = False  # passes
y = 0      # error
```

---

### Why it "still works"

In your case `Timestamp` is a subtype of `str`, so if you were to e.g. annotate `bar: str`, you *could* safely assign `Timestamp` objects to `bar`, but **not the other way around**. (Try it out!) Of course annotating `bar: str` makes no sense practically speaking because the whole point is to have your custom validators, but that does not change the type safety issue.

Pydantic can be very lenient (because Python is dynamically typed) and simply coerce a `str` type value to a `Timestamp` during initialization. And that is exactly what it does.

In fact, that is what Pydantic models do with all sorts of types. You *could* for example just pass `42` (an integer) as the value for your `title` field and the model would coerce that integer to a string. No error would be thrown:

```py
print(Foo(title=42, bar=Timestamp("...")))
```

Output: `title='42' bar='...'`

I hope you see, why any sensible type checker will still mark that as an error since obviously `int` is not (a subtype of) `str`.

---

### Solutions

In practice you have to remember that the type checker follows its own strict logic, which does not always have to line up with your own. That means, if you are *sure* that what you are doing is fine/safe, you always have the option to explicitly **tell** the type checker to ignore something:

```py
def _main() -> None:
    f1 = Foo(
        title="F1",
        bar="2023-04-05T06:07:08Z",  # type: ignore[arg-type]
    )
```

An alternative option with Pydantic is to simply not use the normal constructor in certain cases, but the [`parse_obj`](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/blob/v1.10.7/pydantic/main.py#L518) class method instead:

```py
def _main() -> None:
    f1 = Foo.parse_obj({"title": "F1", "bar": "2023-04-05T06:07:08Z"})
```

Due to the fact that it accepts literally any object, you can pass whatever you want to it and no type checker will ever complain.

But the best option here in my opinion is to avoid obscurity and be type safe, even if it is less convenient. Just pass the `Timestamp` object to `bar` and be done with it.

### PS

You can also use the Pydantic mypy plugin and *not* set the [`init_typed`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/mypy_plugin/#generate-a-signature-for-model__init__) option to `True`. In that case the auto-generated `__init__` signature for **every** model will annotate **all** parameters with `Any`. Then of course mypy will never complain about **any** types being wrong. But I would not recommend that for obvious reasons. Without that option you will receive no mypy errors even if you pass types that are so wrong that even Pydantic cannot sensibly coerce them to correct types, and thus cause runtime errors. Still, that is one way to get rid of that error, so it should be mentioned. Thanks to @python_user for reminding me.

Comment: what are your thoughts on using https://docs.pydantic.dev/mypy_plugin/ ? from my rudimentary testing, the error does not happen if I enable the plugin

Comment: @python_user I am all for it. It is great. I use it myself wherever I use Pydantic. But if you set the [`init_typed`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/mypy_plugin/#generate-a-signature-for-model__init__) option, the error is still there, as it should be. If you don't set that option, all constructor parameters are typed as `Any`. In that case there is no error of course. But I would not recommend that because then mypy will not _ever_ complain about init types.

Comment: Well, yes and no. Your examples with `int` and `bool` are all correct, but there is no Pydantic in play. With the `Timestamp` situation, consider that these two examples are _effectively_ the same:
`Foo(bar=Timestamp("never!!1"))` and `Foo(bar="never!!1")`. They will fail or succeed identically. Of course, only because Pydanitic is involved. So, because Pydantic provides this transparent type coersion, I'm looking for a way to explain this to mypy. Context: I'm coding a library, so code in `_main()` is "anticipated" to be written by its users (and linted with mypy). Still +1

Comment: @frnhr I don't know how else to explain this to you. The type theory aspects here are all very simple and straightforward. Pydantic or not is irrelevant. You cannot "explain" this to mypy because what you are trying to do is **not correct** from the standpoint of a static type checker, i.e. it is not type safe. It is like trying to "explain" that 1+1 is actually 3. I even provided you with 4 distinct workarounds. If none of those work for you, the only option left is to roll your own mypy plugin and "hack" the problem away.

Comment: Sure, there is the _correct_ way to do this from the statically typed POV (explicitly instantiating a `Timestamp`), but then there is also a "more dynamic" way of doing the same (letting Pydantic instantiate a `Timestamp` "magically"). See, if there was a piece of code that turns 1+1 into 3, and that was the expected and documented behaviour, then yes I would expect to have _a way_ of explaining to a checker that this is the case. That's all! Because mypy is not a statically typed _language_, it is a static type checker _for Python_. And yes, `# typing: ignore` is such a way, sort of... Peace!