# Static type checking with Pydantic data conversion

Tags: python, pydantic, pyright

Pydantic offers the means to transform input data into a final type as part of model initialisation. However, this doesn't integrate nicely with static type checkers. Note, I'm using Pydantic 1.X (currently 1.10.12).

For example, consider this model which stores a list of strings. I want the user to be able to initialise it from a file if they want:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, validator

class Foo(BaseModel):
    data: list[str]

    @validator("data", pre=True)
    def read_file(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, str):
            with open(v) as fp:
                return fp.readlines()
        return v

Foo(data = ["a", "b"])
Foo(data = "/etc/hosts")
```

This executes correctly, but running `pyright` on the script gives me:

```
test.py:14:16 - error: Argument of type "Literal['/etc/hosts']" cannot be assigned to parameter "data" of type "list[str]" in function "__init__"
    "Literal['/etc/hosts']" is incompatible with "list[str]" (reportGeneralTypeIssues)
```

Since Pydantic is designed to handle this use case, how can I make it compatible with my type checker? One solution is to make a custom constructor with custom argument types, but this is both redundant and unfeasible for a large number of fields.

Comment: Note, this discusses similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75930775/pydantic-field-with-custom-data-type-and-mypy

Answer (score 2):

First, let's use Pydantic v2 as it's the supported version now.

The original code ported to Pydantic v2 will look like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, field_validator


class Foo(BaseModel):
    data: list[str]

    @field_validator('data', mode='before')
    def read_file(cls, v):
        if isinstance(v, str):
            with open(v) as fp:
                return fp.readlines()
        return v


Foo(data=['a', 'b'])
Foo(data='/etc/hosts')
```

or better

```py
import pathlib
from typing import Annotated, Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, BeforeValidator


def read_file(v: str | pathlib.Path | object) -> list[str]:
    if isinstance(v, str):
        v = pathlib.Path(v)
    if not isinstance(v, pathlib.Path):
        return v
    with open(v) as fp:
        return fp.readlines()


class Foo(BaseModel):
    data: Annotated[list[str], BeforeValidator(read_file)]

Foo(data=['a', 'b'])
Foo(data='/etc/hosts')
```

The code above results in the same errors when being checked with `pyright`.

It's possible to avoid those typing errors using `BaseModel.model_validate()` method. Here is how:

```py
import pathlib
from typing import Annotated, Any

from pydantic import BaseModel, BeforeValidator


def read_file(v: str | pathlib.Path | object) -> list[str]:
    if isinstance(v, str):
        v = pathlib.Path(v)
    if not isinstance(v, pathlib.Path):
        return v
    with open(v) as fp:
        return fp.readlines()


class Foo(BaseModel):
    data: Annotated[list[str], BeforeValidator(read_file)]


Foo.model_validate(dict(data=['a', 'b']))
Foo.model_validate(dict(data='/etc/hosts'))
```

Unlike `BaseModel.__init__()` it accepts an object rather than keywords arguments. This code doesn't raise any typing errors with Pyright.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately in my view `.model_validate(dict())` is just erasing the type checking, and is awfully similar to using `# type: ignore`. An ideal solution here would still check for the existence of the necessary input values, and even better would validate the input types statically.

Comment: The answer gives the recommended solution. You are free to request a feature in the Pydantic Issue Tracker, a PR implementing such a feature would be also welcome.
You can write a class method with an explicit signature or convert a value to another type manually before passing it to validator but all that is just a pure python.

Comment: Thanks, that helped with pydantic 2. I have the same issue with pyright, but i am forced to use pydantic 1 through another dependency. Do you have an idea how to do it with pydantic 1?